# kendoGrid: combobox field from json data

Tags: ajax, combobox, kendo-ui

Here's field:

```
{ field: "category", title: "Category", width: 100, editor: categoryDropDownEditor },
```

custom editor:

```
function categoryDropDownEditor(container, options) {
  console.log('used editor')
  $('<input data-text-field="category" data-value-field="category" data-bind="value:'+options.field+'"/>')
    .appendTo(container)
    .kendoDropDownList({
      autoBind: false,
      dataSource: {
        type: "json",
        transport: {
          read: "/api/notes/dumpcats"
        }
      }
    })
}
```

also in model.fields:

```
  category: {
    type: "combobox",
    editable: true,
    validation: { required: true }
  },
```

No errors, just empty combobox along with input box which errors when category typed in.

Uncaught TypeError: Property '_parse' of object [object Object] is not a function

i used example [here](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/editing-custom.html)

Comment: Could you replicate this issue for us in JSFiddle or JSBin? That would make it easier for us to troubleshoot.  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry man, wouldn't understand how to use those :/

Comment: No problem! Just go to jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com and you can replicate your problem. We can then fork that code and fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue was fixed, as Burke Holland pointed out posting answer below:

```
  function categoryDropDownEditor(contrainer, options) {
    $('<input data-text-field="category" data-value-field="category" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>"')
      .appendTo(contrainer)
      .kendoComboBox({
        index: 0,
        placeholder: "Select category",
        dataTextField: "category",
        dataValueField: "category",
        dataSource: {
          transport: {
            read: {
              url: '/api/notes/cats',
              dataType: 'json',
              type: 'GET',
            },
          },
          schema: {
            data: function(reply) {
              return reply.rows
            },
          }
        }
      })
  }
```